# React modal close

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am a newbie in React. I used bootstrap CDN in the index.html file. I just want to close the bootstrap modal file after a submit. How to do that. Any helps or clue will do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question requires more information.

Comment: I have found a solution
we have to use window.$("id name).modal("hide").

Sorry for you inconvenience.

Comment: If you have a solution you should post it as an answer. Otherwise, delete this post because it offers little to the community. No need to tag me about it--I'm just one of many community volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution we have to use window.$("#idname").modal("hide").